# Swift/XCode how to add a global/safari context menu item?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a macOS application and I would like to add a item to the safari right click menu to send information to my app, here is a video from another app that shows the feature better:

https://carbon-media.accelerator.net/00000000001/dEv3sUX6NeDdQWQ1HnrbwL;1920x1080.mp4

Is it possible to do this from a normal app, or do I have to package/create a new safari extension app? if so, is there any tutorial I can use to package the safari extension into the main app so users don't have to download it twice?

Many thanks

Comment: The browser in that video does not look like Safari...

Comment: right, I would like to do safari first, for chrome and firefox I'm sure one needs to write their own extensions

Comment: My point is that that video does not show that this can be done on Safari. Or is that not your intention?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there is no magic behind it, the way new versions of safari extensions are built are via embedded targets in normal xcode projects, I followed this tutorial and already have something working:

https://ulriklyngs.com/post/2018/11/02/how-to-build-safari-app-extensions/

Cheers